# flask-admin secure the whole admin site but not just the index view

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-admin

I can secure the index view by having my own CustomeIndexView and check whether is authenticated there. But this won't secure a model view, for example, the URL /admin/MyModel/ is still not secured. Is there a way to secure the whole site, basically any url like /admin/xxx/?

one way to do this is by customizing `is_accessible` in `ModelView`. But i still feel it's more straight-forward if it can be done by limiting access by the root url

By the way, i'm using flask-login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `before_request` to check if `current_user.is_authenticated` and return 401 response if not, as in:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if request.full_path.startswith('/admin/'):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated:
            abort(401, 'Please log in')
```

You can also use this to redirect to login page, for example.

Comment: Thanks! I feel this is the best approach

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from `ModelView`:

```
class LoginRequiredView(ModelView):

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for('admin.login', next=request.url))
```

Then use this view instead of `ModelView` to add your model:

```
admin.add_view(LoginRequiredView(User, db.session))
```